# What framework to use to connect to a SQL Server instance from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, sql-server, odbc

I need to write an iPhone application to connect an instance of SQL Server but I can't figure out which framework I could use to do this. Is there an ODBC framework I could use? Any links would be appreciated.

Please do not tell me to use a web service as that won't fit for this situation.

EDIT: I'm building a SQL querying tool for the iPhone. I don't want my users to have to setup a web service if they just want to query a couple tables in their database.

Comment: Can you explain some more about why a web service is not possible? It seems to be the obvious solution, and probably much easier than anything else. If you explain your actual constraints, someone may have a suggestion.

Comment: I'm building a SQL querying tool for the iPhone. I don't want my users to have to setup a web service if they just want to query a couple tables in their database.

Answer (score 1):

As you're undoubtably away, choices for connecting to SQL Server in Objective-C are quite limited. Here are a few options:

- [MacSQL](http://www.rtlabs.com/fwork/) ($699)

  - Commercial product
  - Designed for OS X - no word on iOS compatability
- [ODBC Router](http://odbcrouter.com/ipad) ($799)

  - Another commercial product
  - Appears to funnel requests through a server running special software
- [iSql](http://www.mobilefoo.com/ProductDetail.aspx/iSql) ($25)

  - Commercial
  - Relaies on .Net web service, which can be hosted along side SQL Server database, to act as intermediary

Alternatively, since Objective-C is a superset of C, vanilla C works just fine, though you won't get the inherent "niceness" of working with an OO library. Microsoft has a page on [ODBC Programmer's Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714177%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get you started.